# Issue with styling in IE - Layering a nav

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet

Hey guys I have the following:

```
 <ul class='main_nav'>
        <li class='first' style='padding-top:0;'><a href='#' onclick='return false;'><span class='shaper'>Tools</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='second'><a href='emailfunction.php'>Email Tool</a></li>
                <li class='second'><a href='insurancetool.php'>Insurance Tool</a></li>
                <li class='second'><a href='monthlyreport.php'>Monthly Report Tool</a></li>
                <li class='second'><a href='statuschanger.php'>Status Change Tool</a></li>
                <li class='second'><a href='addtool.php'>Add Tool</a></li>
                <li class='second'><a href='revisetool.php'>Revise Tool</a></li>
                <li class='second'><a href='csvuploaderform.php'>Upload an Employee List (.csv file)</a></li>
                <li class='second'><a href='csvmanualuploaderform.php'>Upload a Single Employee</a></li>
                <li class='second'><a href='insuranceverificationviewer.php'>View Employee Car Insurance Information</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>       
 </ul>
```

So this is my nav and here are the styles:

```
.main_nav {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 118px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #009;
    margin: 0 .5% 0 0;
    padding:0;
    color:black;


}
.main_nav:hover{
    background: lightgray;
    border-top:1px solid #009;
    border-right:1px solid #009;
    border-left:1px solid #009;
    color:#009;
}
.main_nav .first {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color:white;
    z-index:9999;
}
.main_nav li a {
    color:white;
    height:60px;
    display: block; 
    z-index:9999;
}
.main_nav a:hover {
    color:black;    
}
.main_nav li {
    list-style:none;
    z-index:9999;
}
.main_nav li:hover {

}
.main_nav ul {
    display:none;
    list-style:none;    
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    z-index:9999;
}
.main_nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
    background: lightgray;
    }
.main_nav  li ul li {
    border-left:1px solid #009;
    border-right:1px solid #009;
    border-bottom:1px solid #009;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

So this works great and all but in IE I have this issue were I have a div that is absolute that adds a line across the bottom of it.  The thing is in IE that line gets put in front of the top nav that displays when you hover over.  In Google, firefox it is all great.

Here is the bar:

```
<div class="top-backgroundwrap">

</div><!-- top-backgroundwrap -->

.top-backgroundwrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: lightgray;
    margin-top: -24px;  
}
```

I have tried with the z-index and no success.  I notice IE is taking it as by which is the most prev position:absolute; and displaying that in front even after making it's index less.  If you could give me a hand I would appreciate it.  Let me know if you need anything else.

David

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...I have to get rid of the position absolute and change some padding in a seperate IE style sheet.